# Android Studio and Eclipse - re-writing application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

An application re-written in Android Studio won't update the same application written in Eclipse. Package name is the same and version code is higher.

Comment: You must use same keystore while signing application

Comment: Right now I am in debug process. When I run the app, additional app is installed with the same name.

Comment: Post `AndroidManifest.xml` of both apps and `build.gradle`.